# Only print rows that have 2 or more fields?

Tags: awk

I've got a text file and I'm trying to figure out how to filter out any lines with data in only 1 field, leaving lines with 2 fields. I came across the following code: `awk '$NF > 1'`  but I can't get it to work as I want it to. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Here is a sample of my data:

```
simpledaddy11,EastOfBrussels
simpledaddy11,thomaswatkins
simpledaddy11,
simpledaddy11,
simpledaddy11,
simpledaddy11,
simpledaddy11,
simpledaddy11,
simpledaddy11
Moral_Animal,EastOfBrussels
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal,
Moral_Animal
skilur_ua,EastOfBrussels
skilur_ua,thomaswatkins
skilur_ua,
skilur_ua,
skilur_ua,
skilur_ua,
```

Here is what I want to end up with:

```
simpledaddy11,EastOfBrussels
simpledaddy11,thomaswatkins
Moral_Animal,EastOfBrussels
skilur_ua,EastOfBrussels
skilur_ua,thomaswatkins
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12):

If you want to keep lines that have data in at least 2 fields:

```
grep '[^,].*,[^,]'
```

Comment: +1, Would `grep '[^,].*,[^,]'` suffice? I see no reason for the second `.*`?

Comment: This is a good answer. I believe `egrep '[^,],+[^,]'` would also work. But, if the sample data in the question are representative of the actual data, `grep ',.'` is enough.

Answer (score 8):

You need to change the field separator to a comma, also you should not have a `$` before the `NF` if you want the number of fields (`$NF` is the last field). Finally lines ending in a comma are considered to have an empty second field, so you should exclude lines where the last field is blank:

```
awk -F, 'NF>1 && $NF!=""'
```

#### Update

From Stephane's comment, I obviously wasn't reading the question properly. The `awk` to print lines containing more than one non-blank field is more complicated:

```
awk -F, '{ nonblank=0;
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!="") nonblank++
  }
  if(nonblank>1) print $0
}'
```

For this purpose, [Stephane's grep approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118505/48083) is much better.

Comment: whats the difference between `NF` and `$NF`?

Comment: @FDinoff `NF` is the number of fields in the current input record. `$NF` is the last field. Given a record with three fields `a b c`, `NF` will be `3` and `$NF` is equivalent to `$3` which will be `c`

Comment: If the requirement is really to _filter out lines with data in only one field_, then that fails to exclude `,foo`, and that wrongly excludes `foo,bar,`.

Answer (score 1):

you should:

1. set the comma as a "default Field Separator",
2. Question if Number of Fields is major than 1 and if Field number 2 has content.
3. Print the complete row (register) using $0 variable.
4. Your data is stored in the file: data-exercise.txt

This is the code:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}{if(NF>1 && $2!="") print $0;}' data-exercise.txt`

Comment: Or just `awk -F, '$2'`.

Comment: Yes, It works too! Thanks, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams.
`awk -F, '$2' data-exercise.txt`